Is it required to set XMLResolver to null explicitly in order to prevent XXE attacks in DOTNET?
The code I'm using is:
var xmlContent = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><contents>...</contents>";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlContent);

What's the default value of doc.XmlResolver in this case?

What version of .NET or .NET Core are you using?

I'm using .NET 4.8
